# Create/delete disk partitions via WMI

Tags: wmi, disk-partitioning

there is a way to create/delete disk partitions via WMI ?
I'm already able to mount/unmount virtual disks (vhd) and list their partitions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to create/delete partitions in WMI. You may want to look into the [Shell Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762169%28VS.85%29.aspx)